# Can't access xampp server from WAN

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, xampp

So, I ahve installed xampp server on my machine which is running ubuntu. Ufw isn't running on my machine. But when I connect my phone to the router via wifi I can't access it. I already checked httpd.conf and it listens to all ports coming from port 80, not just 127.0.0.1. What can be the issue here?

Comment: can you see port 80 are actually listening ? run `sudo netstat -lntp` to check if it is there. BTW, if you connecting to router's WiFi it probably your LAN, not WAN. Make sure also that your WiFi isn't in a guest or isolated  mode

Comment: Wait weirdly enough it's listening only on tcp6

Comment: Then it something with `httpd.conf`. Does your ubuntu has IPv4? check it in `ifconfig`

Comment: I restarted it, now it's listening to 80. The thing is that I checked with wireshark the connection isn't even coming

Comment: I'd like to fix such issues when the only things you need to do is just restarting :) So try now to turn off wifi on your phone and attempt to connect from outside (WAN) to be make sure port- forwarding set correctly